# Is the solution to this integral involving Bessel function multiplication correct?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, orthogonality, bessel-functions

The orthogonality of the Bessel function of first kind order zero states that:

$$ \int_0^1 rJ_0(R_nr)J_0(R_mr)dr={J_1^2(R_n)\over 2}  \tag 1  $$

where $R_n$ is the $n$-th root of the Bessel function and $R_m=R_n$. I am trying to use this property to solve the following integral:

$$ \int_0^{r_{max}} {r \over r_{max}} J_0\Bigg({R_nr \over r_{max}}\Bigg)J_0\Bigg({R_nr \over r_{max}}\Bigg)dr=? \tag 2  $$

Seems to me that if I use the substitution:

$$ \rho = {r \over r_{max}} \tag 3$$

I get the integral in the form of expression $(1)$:

$$ \int_0^1 \rho J_0(R_n\rho)J_0(R_m\rho)dr={J_1^2(R_n)\over 2}  \tag 4  $$

However, I am not sure if this is correct. I have a feeling that the solution to $(2)$ is actually:

$$ \int_0^{r_{max}} {r \over r_{max}} J_0\Bigg({R_nr \over r_{max}}\Bigg)J_0\Bigg({R_nr \over r_{max}}\Bigg)dr= {r_{max}J_1^2(R_n)\over 2} \tag 5  $$

because of the limits of the integral in expression $(2)$. So my question is, is the integral equation $(2)$ really equal to ${J_1^2(R_n)\over 2}$?

Comment: This is math stack exchange. Decimal notation is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I changed it.